# Would the TWRP for Trend Lite work on Trend 2 Lite?

Tags: twrp

I obtained a secondhand Samsung Galaxy Trend 2 Lite and I am not sure whether [this](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxytrendlite.html) TWRP recovery for Trend Lite is compatible with Trend 2 Lite.

It mentions it is for Samsung Galaxy Trend Device, but I do not know when it mentions Trend also includesTrend 2 as well. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

TWRP, despite it being called a "recovery", actually contains a full kernel to allow other components to run on a specific device, similar to a full ROM.

Due to this, many smallest differences (usually except storage size) can make a certain recovery don't run on another model.

In your case, they run on different, incompatible SoCs, so the TWRP for Trend Lite will **not** work on Trend 2 Lite.